# Finding $\int_{S}^{} x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})\,dx\,dy\,dz$ where $S$ is part of a sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

> Let $S$ be the subset of the sphere $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 1,  z > 0$. Calculate the integral $$\int_{S}^{} x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

So I know that this is a surface integral. I used these parameters:

$$\boldsymbol{\mathbf{}\Phi} (\varphi ,\theta )=(\sin \varphi \cos \theta, \sin \varphi \sin \theta, \cos \varphi) , 0<\varphi < \frac{\pi}{2}, 0<\theta<2\pi$$ I also found $$\left \| \Phi_{\phi} \times \Phi_{\theta} \right \| = \sin \varphi$$
So I got the double integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin^{4}\varphi\cos^{4}\theta \sin(\sin^{3}\varphi \cos^{3}\theta \cos^{5}\varphi)\sin\varphi \,d\varphi \,d\theta $$ but I don't think that it's a good idea.

Comment: Maybe Stokes' Theorem?

Comment: @FormerMath Is it easy to find $\boldsymbol{F}$ such that $\triangledown  \times \boldsymbol{F} = x^{4}\sin(x^{3}z^{5})$ ?

Comment: $x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})$ is an odd function wrt $x$ and as sphere is symmetric to $YZ$ plane, the integral will be zero.

Comment: From the fact it's a triple integral, do we really want to integrate over the half-ball $x^2+y^2+z^2\le1,\,z>0$?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $f(x,y,z) = x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})$. We have for all $(x,y,z) \in S$

$$f(x,y,z) = -f(-x,y,z)$$ and therefore

$$\int_{S}^{} x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})dxdydz=0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I couldn't see this unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$\int_{S}^{} x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})dxdydz
\\= \int_{S, x>0}^{} x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})dxdydz+ 
\int_{S, x<0}^{} x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})dxdydz\\
 = \int_{S, x>0}^{} x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})dxdydz-
\int_{S, x>0}^{} x^{4} \sin (x^{3}z^{5})dxdydz=0
$$

Comment: ohhhhh it was easier that I thought. I couldn't see it. Thanks a lot!